# Rebus #19 is here

Tags: rebus

I'd rather play it or listen to it. ;)

[image]

***EDIT***:  This is an expression, not a word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it

> Face the music

Because

> There is a guy facing music notes.

Comment: Ohh! Everything makes sense with this!

Comment: A noteworthy answer!  Will do the check when it lets me.

Answer (score 3):

Well there is a word called

> headnote

Comment: I'll give you 2nd place (if I had meant that word,  there'd only be one note, though, & I'd have used a post-it or ordinary written note).  Thanx for adding another word to my vocabulary! :)

Comment: @Wordster headnotes is also a word :)

Comment: Absolutely!  That's why I'm giving you 2nd place. :)

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer

> iTunes

Like

> The image of the face draws attention the the eyes.
>  So eye + tunes

Comment: Interesting spin on it, but not quite, sorry.  I'd have used only one *** if I had wanted that word.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> <strike>Song stuck in your head?</strike> Headsong?

Comment: Good guess, but not quite, sorry!